Unpaid because of equipment issue
I am working from home, but suddenly my CPU is not working last Wednesday shift. I was able to raise it with my supervisor and IT as well and I do have a ticket as a reference and a video that my cpu is not working.
The IT told me that I need to send it back to them to check and so I did. And gladly it works. I was able to work again Thursday shift.
Friday comes and my CPU is not working again. I was able to raise it again to IT and my supervisor. The IT told me that the CPU is now subject for replacement, and I went again to the office.
Imagine how much I spent for my transportation because I went to the office twice.
Now my supervisor told me that my 2 days absence is unpaid because it is company policy.
But my wave mate told me that he had the same issue and her 1 day absence is paid.
My question is, do I deserve to get unpaid for my 2 days absence because of a technical issue?

"Deserve" means nothing here except emotional validation. This is entirely a matter of company policy and your manager's application of it. If you think they might not be applying it properly you can get a slip level meeting with your manager's manager and ask them, or ask HR. There really isn't much more we can tell you. Good luck. (In my imagination, going in to the office twice isn't a huge hardship, by the way; but that's between you and manglement.)

Is this failing equipment company equipment, or is it yours? Where in the world do you live? Your countries laws may have something to say about this, but as you can imagine, they vary wildly between countries. What might be normal in the US would be highly illegal in Europe. We cannot tell you what you "deserve", if you add a country tag, we might be able to tell you what your rights are concerning this.

We also have problems "imagining" how much you spent. When I go to the office, I spent maybe 2-3$ on gas. It would be 5$ if I had to take public transport, and it would be 10$ if I bought a coffee on the way. Maybe your office is in another federal state and you spent 200$ on a red-eye flight? We have no idea. Feel free to add details.

Working from home is not a right - unless you have that in a contract.
If there isn't anything stopping you from taking the broken computer with you to the office. Take it and ask IT to swap it out before the end of you shift.
I don't mean to sound harsh, but what are you expecting for answers?
Computer broke? Go to the office - work a day and get the computer swapped out.

That's assuming there's a computer in the office that can be used. My company works on laptops, if mine breaks down, there's no machine at the office to work on.
